# Complex multi-valued function with singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \hat{\mathbb{C}} := \mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$
a multi-valued function  in the context of complex analysis with
$f(0) = \infty$.

The question is why this function $f$ can be near $0$
locally expanded as

$$ g(z) + A \cdot log \ z +B z^{-1}+ C z^{-2}+ ... $$

with $g(z)$ finite and holomorphic near $0$, the $A, B, C,...$
appropriate complex comstanats and $log \ z$ the (multivalued)
complex logarithm?
So the question is what kind of branch point
[branch point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point) a singularity of $f$ might have? The expansion about
suggests that the only kind of branches may occure are
the *logarithmic* ones if we assume $f(0) = \infty$ (ie that
$0$ is singular point). That means that $0$
cannot be an algebraic or non logarithmic transcendental branch point. Why?

(here I implicitely assume that a multivalued function $h(z)$ with singuarity in $0$ *logarithmically* branches in $0$ iff locally $h= log \ z + g(z)$ where $g(z)$ is *single-valued* meromorphic function; is this definition of logarithmic branch correct? Looks reasonable to me, but haven't seen this definition in literature, so beside the concern of 'main question' I would like to know if that's what I wrote in previous sentence is a conventional definition of logarithmical branch)

The background of this question is an unproved statement
in Riemann's 'Theorie der Abelschen Functionen' I intended
to discuss in [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386960/expansion-around-a-singular-point-of-a-multivalued-meromorphic-function-due-to)
but there was attested to me too little basic knowledge. But I don't know
any textbook on complex analysis which provide exactly that backgrond to discuss *this* broblem or where this problem is
discussed. Nevertheless I humbly think that I already have
a certain amount of basic knowledge on complex analysis.
So possibly mse might be a better place to discuss this problem.

Comment: $\lim_{|z|\to 0} |(1+z)\log z|=\infty$ too and it can't be expanded as you said. Same for $z^{-1/2}$. When $f(z)-a\log z$ has an isolated singularity at $0$ we are willing to know it, in this context saying it has a logarithmic branch point is fine, even if most people would think that $f(a)-a\log z$ is analytic, no pole or essential singularity.

Comment: @reuns: Yes, that's a good conterexample that if we not not impose
additional assumptions on $f$ the 
expansion $g + A \cdot log \ z +B z^{-1}+ C z^{-2}+ ...$
of $f$ may not exist and Riemann's remark is wrong.

One possible way out of this problem suggested by Will Sawin
(https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386960/expansion-around-a-singular-point-of-a-multivalued-meromorphic-function-due-to)

is that possibly I somewhere overlooked that Riemann maybe considers there
functions with

Comment: single-valued derivative or the only multi-valued
function which Riemann studied during his lifetime
when he 'invented' Riemann surfaces were those which have single-valued derivative,
I don't know. Then of course the expansion above is literally tailor-made
*only* with multi-valued functions with single-valued derivative.

Comment: Another remark on your example. Do you know if, when we start with an arbitrary multi-valued
function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ with *logarithmic branch point*
(https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Logarithmic_branch_point)

in $0$, can this function locally near $0$ be always expanded
as an element of the ring $(\mathbb{C}[z, z^{-1},log \ z]$, 
ie the $\mathbb{C}$-agebra generated by $z, z^{-1},log \ z$?

Comment: Your link doesn't make any sense. No idea why you want to consider the ring generated by $\log z$.

Comment: Alexandre Eremenko is 100% right and asking on mathoverflow doesn't make much sense.

Comment: My motivation was to know if that is somehow possible
to find a way to express every multi-valued 
function with with branch point in $0$. 
According to https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Branch_point
there are three kinds of branch points: algebraic bp and
transcendental pb (where they distinguish between logarithmic 
tra pb and non logarithmic). In case of transcendental *non*
logarithmic pb and algebraic bp in $a$ the function can be locally 
expanded as $f(z)= \sum _{v= - \infty} ^{+ \infty} b_v(z-a)^{-v/k}$

Comment: in Puiseux series. So all information about $f$ is encoded 
in coefficients $b_v$. Logarithmic bp not allows such expansion, so I was asking 
myself if it may be also possible to expand multi-valued function
with logarithmic bp if we make the ring "bigger" then that
one where Puiseux series live. But yes, I don't know 
if it make any sense, that was just a thought.

Comment: About the comment of Alexandre Eremenko: the point that irritated me a bit
there was that the main reason for asking that question was due to 
him only based 
on lack of my knowledge of basic notions in complex analysis. But I think 
the problem is the kack of knowledge of historical background there.
The classification of branch points like I mentioned above 
wasn't known there so it is not easy to know without this 
historical background (which one cannot find some modern Complex 
variables book) why all functions Riemann considers there
should have such expansion

Comment: $g(z) + A \cdot \log \ z +B z^{-1}+ C z^{-2}+ \ldots$ as
Riemann stated. As your conterexample above shows it seems
that he not considered *arbitrary* multi-valued functions, 
but to know it isn't a matter of experience on a mathematical
field, but a matter of historical knowledge and 
I don't know why it shouldn't be reasonable to ask in mo a question
on historical background which somebody might better know 
than the questioner. Or did I have misunderstood his or your comment?

Comment: There is no classification of branch points. $0$ is a branch point whenever $f(e^{-z})$ is analytic and non-$2i\pi$ periodic for $\Re(z)>c$. Algebraic branch points are a special case, with $f(z^n)$ being meromorphic.